# Как корректно изменить тип <class 'telebot.types.Contact'>, чтобы можно было сохранить данные в БД?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Подскажите, пожалуйста:

есть ли возможность изменить тип данных у сообщения, содержащего данные о контакте,
в такой, чтобы данные из этого массива можно было сохранить в БД?

Сейчас имею данные в формате `<class 'telebot.types.Contact'>`:

```
{
    'phone_number': '+799999999', 
    'first_name': 'Name', 
    'last_name': 'Lastname', 
    'user_id': 999999, 
    'vcard': None
}
```

Пробовала изменить тип на словарь, но это явно неверный путь решения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы записал в json.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["contact"])
def get_contact(message: types.Message):
    contact = message.contact.__dict__
    json_contafct = json.dumps(contact, ensure_ascii=False) # <- type str
```

Ну и потом, с помощью, `json` модуля распарсить обратно в словарь.

UPD. Хотя нет. Я бы просто вытащил номер телефона и записал бы его в БД.
`contact = message.contact.phone_number`

Comment: Спасибо огромное!